# very slow loading calendar events, any way to optimize?

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a calendar that is working successfully, but the load times are very slow.  Each event is rendered successfully, but the user has to wait a good 5-10 seconds when switching views or navigating through the months/weeks/days.

I have shown the event loading code below, is there anything I can do to it to make it load faster?

Thanks

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function () {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //events: [{"title":"My Test Event","start":"Wed, 02 Nov 2011 13:00:00 EST","url":"http://edu","allDay":"false"}],

        events: "JSONcalendarFeed.aspx",

        defaultView: 'month',
        weekends: false,
        allDay: false,
        minTime: 8,
        maxTime: 19,
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotMinutes: 15,
        weekMode: 'liquid',
        defaultEventMinutes: 60,
        firstHour: 8,
        header: {
            left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev,next today'
        },
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            var evtDesc = event.description;
            var evtStart = event.start;
            var evtEnd = event.end;
            if (evtDesc || evtStart) {
                element.qtip(
                    {
                        content: evtStart + ' - ' + evtEnd + '<br/>' + evtDesc,
                        position: {
                            corner: {
                                target: 'bottomMiddle',
                                tooltip: 'topMiddle'
                            }
                        },
                        style: {
                            name: 'light'
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: false,
                        weekends: false
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        editable: true
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong, how does your JSONcalendarFeed.aspx look? Do you get the same behavior when uncommenting the row with the static events?

Comment: Well the test static event isn't much, so it loads really fast.  The JSON feed takes about 3 seconds to load by itself.  It is only loaded once as it loads events for the entire year.  I have the calendar set to lazy fetch so it should be able to zip through each month and week. - Thanks

Comment: You could try to read the start and end parameters sent by fullCalendar to only send the events between those dates from the feed to reduce the loading time. I can't really remember why but I set my lazyFetching to false for some reason. Tried that? As I said before, can't see anything wrong in the code you published.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean about sending the start and end parameters to only send the events between those dates...how can I tell fullCalendar to do that?  - Thanks

Comment: fullCalendar already does this.. Check out http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ start and end parameters as unix timestamp (in seconds) are sent with every request for events.

Comment: My calendar page calls the JSON feed once...so I don't have to do multiple pageloads.  Do you think I should call JSON feed every time the calendar needs updated?  Thanks

Comment: I think that's a good idea yes. fullCalendar automatically fetches event every time you change the view or browse the months. You should only send the events that occurs during the time that is shown.

Comment: wait...i'm confused...so fullCalendar is calling my JSONcalendarFeed.aspx page everytime I navigate to another month, week, or day?  -thanks

Comment: Yes it does. That's why you need to read start and end parameters..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

Don't send all events from the feed but only the ones that occurs between *start* and *end* which are parameters sent by fullCalendar to the feed-page. These are sent as unix timestamps in **seconds**.

Comment: I blew up our production server by thinking the timestamps were sent as milliseconds, and fetching one day ahead and one day behind the given range (which actually turned out to be 1000 days ahead and behind)!  It made it through testing b/c our test data sample wasn't large enough. Ooops.

Comment: LOL. I made the same mistake, however without blowing anything up. That's why I always bold the seconds part. =)

Comment: Hi can you elaborate it further? Maybe by means of example?