# Fullcalendar rendering 2000 events

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, fullcalendar

I've a fullcalendar script running but I need to render about 2000 to 3000 events.

I already [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313953/very-slow-loading-calendar-events-any-way-to-optimize) and I've done that (Only load the events between start and end date). Then I've made the JSON call so that Javascript only have to send it to fullcalender. Also, I don't use renderEvent.

But the rendering of the events is still very slow. The ajax call takes about 400 milliseconds after the successful call the browser is taking about 5 to 10 seconds to render all the events.

Where else can I gain speed?

Comment: Hi :), did you solve this issue?

Comment: I made costum elements with just a div with a text:
<div id="blabla">Label</div>
Then on click on the calender the parent of the elements, i fetch the click check if the id is correct and then do stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that data is retrieved within a few hundreds of milliseconds, there's no bottleneck with the connection. In my experience, if you have page with more than 4000 DOM elements, the browser will slow down significantly due to browser rendering engine is incapable of rendering that large amount of elements. So with 2000 to 3000 events times it by 3 or more depends how you structure the html for each event like DIV, SPAN, BR... that would be al least 12000 DOM elements on the page.

The solution is segmenting the data. Break it down to smaller pieces, and display events when necessary.

Comment: I understand what you mean but i think i already done that or are you saying i should break down fullcalender? Like removing the .content div in the event div?

Comment: Other question (i was just thinking off) if i retreve the json data i put it in an javascrupt array so if i click on the calender i check if i clicked on an event en than add tiptop (jq plugin) to it with the data from the array i made earlier. Does this array slow down things?

Comment: it can be quite slow if you have a large amount of data in array because it's stored in memory. I think you should strategy how to show the events on the calendar, ie: display events per person,group, or category.

Comment: That could be an solution. But one of the categoriees is over 2000 events a week.

Comment: And css? Gradiants borders etc? Is this expensive?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of events rendered for each day by using [eventLimit](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimit/)

Comment: But the challenge is not to limit the events, but to limit the elements in the events.